# flutter didUpdateWidget() lifecycle is never call

Tags: flutter, state

**Context :**
I develop a desktop flutter application into a windows 11 OS system.

**Requirements :**
I need to add bar tab app. Each tab represent one route/screen to display.
If route never call before then add tab but if already exist then focus on this
if tab is close then reopen the sibling tab.
On each rebuild widget I need to have to know the previous state value to know the tab already created in the past and not reset all the tab on each rebuild.
I want to use the lifecycle function widget didUpdateWidget() for retrieve last/old state value and knowing others tab already open and the position.

**issue :**
My tabApp widget never run didUpdateWidget(). I don't understand because my widget real rebuild and graphically change. The route and navigation run correctly. I try 3 different ways but nothing resolve my issue.

---

**1st test :**

*I try to use variable component layout (not in state class linked) which use to call tabApp*

```
classLayoutextendsStatefulWidget
{
  finalWidgetchild;
  finalStringtargetURI;

  const Layout({super.key,requiredthis.child,requiredthis.targetURI});

  @override
  State<Layout> createState ()=> _LayoutState();
}

class_LayoutState extends State<Layout>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return WindowBorder(
      color:Colors.red,
      child:Column(
        children:[
          TabApp(targetURI:widget.targetURI),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Layout(child:HomeContentScreen(), targetURI:'home');
  }
}

class HomeContentScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const HomeContentScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeContentScreen> createState ()=> _HomeContentScreenState();
}

class _HomeContentScreenState extends State<HomeContentScreen>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContextcontext){}
}


class BoardScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const BoardScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BoardScreen> createState ()=> _BoardScreenState();
}

class _BoardScreenState extends State<BoardScreen>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContextcontext)
  {
    return Layout(child:BoardContentScreen(), targetURI:'board');
  }
}

class BoardContentScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const BoardContentScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BoardContentScreen> createState ()=> _BoardContentScreenState();
}

class _BoardContentScreenState extends State<BoardContentScreen>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContextcontext){}
}
```

---

**2d test :**

*I try to include variable targetURI into state class of layout component which change on each navigation change and use to call tabApp widget*

```
class Layout extends StatefulWidget
{
  final Widget child;
  final String targetURI;

  const Layout({super.key, required this.child, required this.targetURI});

  @override
  State<Layout> createState() => _LayoutState();
}

class _LayoutState extends State<Layout>
{
  late String targetURI = '';

  @override
  void initState() 
  {

    targetURI = widget.targetURI;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant Layout oldWidget)
  {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return WindowBorder(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Column(
        children: [
            TabApp(targetURI: targetURI),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}



class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState ()=> _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Layout(child:HomeContentScreen(), targetURI:'home');
  }
}

class HomeContentScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const HomeContentScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeContentScreen> createState ()=> _HomeContentScreenState();
}

class _HomeContentScreenState extends State<HomeContentScreen>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContextcontext){}
}



class BoardScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const BoardScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BoardScreen> createState ()=> _BoardScreenState();
}

class _BoardScreenState extends State<BoardScreen>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContextcontext)
  {
    return Layout(child:BoardContentScreen(), targetURI:'board');
  }
}

class BoardContentScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const BoardContentScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BoardContentScreen> createState ()=> _BoardContentScreenState();
}

class _BoardContentScreenState extends State<BoardContentScreen>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContextcontext){}
}
```

---

**3th test :**

*I try to use the key parameter widget with random number for forcing rebuild widget on each change route.
For layout component AND screen component*

```
class Layout extends StatefulWidget
{
  final Widget child;
  final String targetURI;

  const Layout({super.key, required this.child, required this.targetURI});

  @override
  State<Layout> createState() => _LayoutState();
}

class _LayoutState extends State<Layout>
{
  late String targetURI = '';

  @override
  void initState() {

    targetURI = widget.targetURI;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant Layout oldWidget)
  {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    intnumber=Random().nextInt(9999999);
    return WindowBorder(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Column(
        children: [
            TabApp(targetURI: targetURI, key: ValueKey('targetURI$number')),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    int number = Random().nextInt(9999999);

    print(number);

    return Layout(child: HomeContentScreen(key: ValueKey('home$number')), targetURI: 'home', key: ValueKey('home$number'),);
  }
}

class HomeContentScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const HomeContentScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeContentScreen> createState() => _HomeContentScreenState();
}

class _HomeContentScreenState extends State<HomeContentScreen>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
}




class BoardScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const BoardScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BoardScreen> createState ()=> _BoardScreenState();
}

class _BoardScreenState extends State<BoardScreen>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContextcontext)
  {
    intnumber=Random().nextInt(9999999);    returnLayout(child:BoardContentScreen(key:ValueKey('board$number'),),targetURI:'board',key:ValueKey('board$number'),);
       }
  }

class BoardContentScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  const BoardContentScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BoardContentScreen> createState ()=> _BoardContentScreenState();
}

class _BoardContentScreenState extends State<BoardContentScreen>
{
  @override
  Widgetbuild(BuildContextcontext){}
}
```

==================================================================================

- why, in this 3 tests, didUpdateWidget() is never call into tabApp widget ?
- I also try to delete all const declaration but nothing change